# Issues with aligning text boxes

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have this code 1 which creates the scnario in picture 1.

```
 <p>Ditt namn (obligatorisk)<br />                          
    [text* your-name]</p>                                         

<p>Din epost (obligatorisk)<br />
    [email* your-email] </p>

<p>Ditt telefonnummer<br />
    [tel tel-621] </p>

<p>Ämne<br />
    [select menu-101 include_blank "Konstruktions ritningar" "Visualisering" "Mjukvara utveckling" "Övrigt"]</p>

<p>Ditt meddelande<br />
   [textarea your-message] </p>

<p>[submit "Skicka"]</p>
```

[image: Picture 1]

After hours of trying I can not seem to get the message box appear right to the **ditt namn** -box. Does anybody have a clue what I can do to somehow align the messagebox right to the **Ditt namn**?

Thankful for any kind of help,

/ Rinor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using `display:inline-block;`. See example below:

HTML:

```
 <div class="left">
   <p>Ditt namn (obligatorisk)<br />                          
     [text* your-name]</p>
   <p>Din epost (obligatorisk)<br />
     [email* your-email] </p>
   <p>Ditt telefonnummer<br />
     [tel tel-621] </p>
   <p>Ämne<br />
     [select menu-101 include_blank "Konstruktions ritningar" "Visualisering" "Mjukvara utveckling" "Övrigt"]</p>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
   <p>Ditt meddelande<br />
     [textarea your-message] </p>
 </div>
 <p>[submit "Skicka"]</p>
```

CSS:

`.left, .right {display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width:45%;}`

Comment: Hi, That did the job! Thank you very much.

Comment: By the way it became a styling error on the mobile site. How come :)?

Comment: you can style it with `media queries` for mobile devices [standard media queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)